# Почему fs.appendFile работает до бесконечности с окончанием js в Node.js

Tags: node.js

когда Я использовал .txt работала нормально один раз написал в файле data to append;

```
const fs =require('fs');

fs.appendFile('vzgo.txt', 'data to append', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');
});
```

но когда я использую  .js  окончание  то тогда работает до бесконечности;

```
const fs =require('fs');

    fs.appendFile('vzgo.js', 'data to append', (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');
    });
```

Comment: что значит работает до бесконечности? все нормально работает

Comment: Почему во втором случае отступ больше на уровень? Внутри чего эта конструкция находится?

Comment: я снял видео посмотрите 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTWW4Qr24sU&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Потому что Вы используете nodemon, который обнаруживая изменение .js-файла, перезапускает проект.

Comment: так вы бы сразу сказали про `nodemon`, у него есть опция `ignore`, куда нужно передать файл(ы), которые не нужно отслеживать `nodemon --ignore './vzgo.js' --exec ./app.js`